# Copy input from one place and use it as a variable or in another area using onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to take values from one of these input boxes and duplicate them in another input box. This action would be very useful in another project I'm working on but, I can seem to get it to work. 
What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/qBFAe/

HTML

```
Field1: <input type="text" id="field1" />
<br />
Field2: <input type="text" id="field2" />
<br /><br />
Click the button to copy the content of Field1 to Field2.
<br />
<button id="convert">Copy Text</button>
```

JS

```
var converter = document.getElementById("convert");
var ff2 = document.getElementById('field2');
var ff1 = document.getElementById('field1');
convert.onclick = fillFun();

function fillFun(){
ff2.value=ff1.value;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this after elements are loaded, in the `window.onload` event, plus assign the function as the event handler properly (without parentheses). Fixed code:

```
var ff2 = null;
var ff1 = null;

window.onload = function() {
    ff2 = document.getElementById('field2');
    ff1 = document.getElementById('field1');
    var converter = document.getElementById("convert");
    converter.onclick = fillFun;
};


function fillFun(){
    ff2.value = ff1.value;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBFAe/2/).

Comment: Note that the code in the JS field of jsFiddle is already in `window.onload`!

Comment: Thanks @Adam didn't notice the typo! :blush:

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. <s>You assign `onclick` to `convert` and not to `converter`!</s> Because the JavaScript code already runs in `window.onload` in jsFiddle, you simply can access `convert`.
2. And you set `onclick` to the return value of `fillFun()`. You don't must have brackets!

The corrected code:
http://jsfiddle.net/qBFAe/1/

```
var converter = document.getElementById("convert");
var ff2 = document.getElementById('field2');
var ff1 = document.getElementById('field1');
converter.onclick = fillFun;

function fillFun(){
    ff2.value=ff1.value;

}
```

Comment: jsFiddle is adding its own `window.load`, it's pretty confusing.. to imitate real environment, you have to choose "no wrap" option.